# Downloading HTML page with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, wininet

Here is my code. I have attached wininet.lib to additional dependencies.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HINTERNET hSession, hURL;
    char* Buffer = new char[1024];
    DWORD BufferLen, BytesWritten;
    HANDLE FileHandle;

    hSession = InternetOpen(NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
    hURL = InternetOpenUrl(hSession, "http://www.google.co.uk", NULL, 0, 0, 0);

    FileHandle = CreateFile("C:\temp.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if (FileHandle == NULL) { cout << "FileHandle == NULL" << endl; }
    BytesWritten = 0;
    do
    {
        InternetReadFile(hURL, Buffer, 1024, &BufferLen);
        WriteFile(FileHandle, Buffer, BufferLen, &BytesWritten, NULL);
    } while (BufferLen != 0);
    CloseHandle(FileHandle);

    InternetCloseHandle(hURL);
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);

    ShellExecute(0, "open", "C:\\temp.txt", NULL, NULL, 1);

    cout << "Operation complete!" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

My output file C:\temp.txt is not created even though the handle is non-null. I would like to know why this is the case and if the rest of my code is correct. Thank you.

Comment: You probably meant to write "C:\\temp.txt" at the first parameter of CreateFile. your version means C:(TAB)emp.txt

Comment: Write access to C:\\ is restricted in modern versions of Windows, you should add some return code checking.

Comment: You both are correct. I changed to C:\\Users\\Danny\\Desktop\\temp.txt and it worked. Thank you both; it was a very frustrating error.